# Dynamically create password fields in Oracle APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

How is it possible to dynamically create password type input fields in Oracle APEX 19.2? Read about using APEX_ITEM package, but there is no function for password fields there.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem as well and I had to come up with my own solution, here it is:

**First, create your APEX_ITEM with a special class name** (I have used 'pwd')
In the following example I'll imagine we are creating the Item inside a report:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.TEXT( 1, field_value, NULL, NULL, 'class="pwd"' ) AS pwd_column_name FROM DUAL
```

**After the field has been created run javascript to find the inputs with class 'pwd'** and change their type to 'password'. (e.g. on the report add a Dynamic Action -> After Refresh -> Execute Javascript code)

```
$('.pwd').attr('type', 'password');
```